# Query with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table :** Students

```
  ID    Name    Marks
    1   Ashley   81
    2   Samantha 75
    4   Julia    76
    3   Belvet   84
```

A query to return the name where marks is greater than 75, output will be sorted by last three characters of each name,if ties,then sort with ascending ID.

My Query:-

```
  Select Name 
    From Students 
   Where Marks > 75
Order By (Select Substring(Name,1,2))
```

I tried this so far,I tried to figure out `order by` someway,but this is wrong . How could I accomplish it?

Comment: Remove select from order by. Substring alone will do the trick.

Comment: why do you select again in the order by? (including that you are missing the table if you´d really wanted to do so)

Comment: Should this homework question have been answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Students 
WHERE Marks > 75
ORDER BY RIGHT(Name, 3),
         ID
```

You could also use:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name)-2, 3)
```

as an alternative.

Comment: I just tried it back and forth now, `SUBSTRING` seems very tolerant, it even works correctly if the `Name` has only one character. Of course still `RIGHT` looks better.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `SELECT` in the `ORDER BY` clause. And to order by the *last* three characters instead of the *first* use this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Students 
WHERE Marks > 75
ORDER BY RIGHT(Name, 3), ID
```

To order ties by `ID` just add `ID` as second `ORDER` argument.

Comment: does substring(Name, LEN (Name) - 3, 3 ) give last three characters of the names?

Comment: no,substring(Name, LEN (Name) - 3, 3 ) is not giving last three chars...

Comment: @Zahid sorry, you're right, SQL strings are obviously 1-indexed, so it's `LEN()-2`.

Comment: What would happen with `SUBSTRING('Bo', 0, 3)` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as you can see when you put this line your SQL tool, it returns `'Bo' `

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Students 
WHERE Marks > 75
ORDER BY substring(Name, LEN(Name)-2, 3), ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the part you need. Order by it, then id.

```
select substring('THENAME', LENGTH('THENAME')-2, 3)
```

Whole code:

```
Select Name from Students 
where Marks > 75
order by (Substring(Name,LENGTH(Name)-2,3)), Id
```

Answer (score -2):

Make this function in sql:

```
Alter function dbo.getlastthreechar (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(3)
   with schemabinding<
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(256)
   set @s2 = ''
   set @s2 = RIGHT(@s,3)
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```

Then you would query like:

```
Select Name from Students where Marks > 75 order by dbo.getlastthreechar(Name )
```

Comment: RIGHT(name,3) gives last three character from string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.